# Bluetooth with Android Service Discovery Failed

Tags: android, macos, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I have a problem with `bluetooth` in Android, I follow the tutorial in the android developer but I am not able to connect to a paired device in Android, I am using android studio and this is my code:

```
public class BluetootConectionManager
{
    private static final String TAG = "BLUETOOTH CONECTION";
    public static BluetootConectionManager BLUETOOTH_MANAGER= new BluetootConectionManager();

    private BluetoothStateListener mBluetoothStateListener = null;

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID UUID_OTHER_DEVICE = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");

    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;

    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "Bluetooth Secure";

    private ConnectedThread mConnectedThread;
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;

    private int mState;

    public interface BluetoothStateListener
    {
        public void onServiceStateChanged(int state);
    }

    public BluetootConectionManager()
    {
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        mState = BluetoothState.STATE_NONE;
        mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    }

    public void setBluetoothStateListener(BluetoothStateListener listener)
    {
        this.mBluetoothStateListener = listener;
    }


    public String[] getPairedDeviceName() {
        int c = 0;
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        String[] name_list = new String[devices.size()];
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            name_list[c] = device.getName();
            c++;
        }
        return name_list;
    }

    public String[] getPairedDeviceAddress() {
        int c = 0;
        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = mAdapter.getBondedDevices();
        String[] address_list = new String[devices.size()];
        for(BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
            address_list[c] = device.getAddress();
            c++;
        }
        return address_list;
    }



    public synchronized int getState()
    {
        return mState;
    }

    // CONECTAR CON DISPOSITIVOS
    public synchronized void connect(String address)
    {
        BluetoothDevice device = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
        connect(device);
    }


    public synchronized void connect(BluetoothDevice device)
    {
        // Cancel any thread attempting to make a connection
        if (mState == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTING)
        {
            if (mConnectThread != null)
            {
                mConnectThread.cancel();
                mConnectThread = null;
            }
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        // Start the thread to connect with the given device
        mConnectThread = new ConnectThread(device);
        mConnectThread.start();
        setState(BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTING);
    }

    // METODO PARA OBTENER CONEXIONES ENTRANTES
    public synchronized void start()
    {
        if (mConnectThread != null)
        {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }
        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        setState(BluetoothState.STATE_LISTEN);
        if (mSecureAcceptThread == null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread = new AcceptThread();
            mSecureAcceptThread.start();
        }
    }

    public synchronized void stop() {
        if (mConnectThread != null) {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        if (mConnectedThread != null) {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread.kill();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }
        setState(BluetoothState.STATE_NONE);

    }


    public void send(byte[] data, boolean CRLF) {
        if(getState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            if(CRLF) {
                byte[] data2 = new byte[data.length + 2];
                for(int i = 0 ; i < data.length ; i++)
                    data2[i] = data[i];
                data2[data2.length - 0] = 0x0A;
                data2[data2.length] = 0x0D;
                write(data2);
            } else {
                write(data);
            }
        }
    }

    public void send(String data, boolean CRLF) {
        if(getState() == BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            if(CRLF)
                data += "\r\n";
            write(data.getBytes());
        }
    }




    private void write(byte[] out) {
        // Create temporary object
        ConnectedThread r;
        // Synchronize a copy of the ConnectedThread
        synchronized (this) {
            if (mState != BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED) return;
            r = mConnectedThread;
        }
        // Perform the write unsynchronized
        r.write(out);
    }


    private void connectionFailed() {
        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetootConectionManager.this.start();
    }

    // Indicate that the connection was lost and notify the UI Activity
    private void connectionLost() {
        // Start the service over to restart listening mode
        BluetootConectionManager.this.start();
    }

    private synchronized void setState(int state)
    {
        mState = state;
        // Give the new state to the Handler so the UI Activity can update
        mBluetoothStateListener.onServiceStateChanged(state);
    }


    // session in listening (server) mode. Called by the Activity onResume()


    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device)
        {
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket for a connection with the
            // given BluetoothDevice
            try
            {
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID_OTHER_DEVICE);
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Always cancel discovery because it will slow down a connection
            mAdapter.cancelDiscovery();


            // Make a connection to the BluetoothSocket
            try {
                // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                // successful connection or an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Close the socket
                e.printStackTrace();
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e2)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                connectionFailed();
                return;
            }

            // Reset the ConnectThread because we're done
            synchronized (BluetootConectionManager.this) {
                mConnectThread = null;
            }


            // Start the connected thread
            connected(mmSocket, mmDevice);
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void connected(BluetoothSocket socket, BluetoothDevice
            device)
    {
        // Cancel the thread that completed the connection
        if (mConnectThread != null)
        {
            mConnectThread.cancel();
            mConnectThread = null;
        }

        // Cancel any thread currently running a connection
        if (mConnectedThread != null)
        {
            mConnectedThread.cancel();
            mConnectedThread = null;
        }

        if (mSecureAcceptThread != null) {
            mSecureAcceptThread.cancel();
            mSecureAcceptThread = null;
        }


        // Start the thread to manage the connection and perform transmissions
        mConnectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
        mConnectedThread.start();

        // Send the name of the connected device back to the UI Activity

        setState(BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED);
    }

    // This thread runs during a connection with a remote device.
    // It handles all incoming and outgoing transmissions.
    private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket)
        {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the BluetoothSocket input and output streams
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;

        }

        public void run() {

            byte[] buffer;
            ArrayList<Integer> arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int data = mmInStream.read();
                    if(data == 0x0A) {
                    } else if(data == 0x0D) {
                        buffer = new byte[arr_byte.size()];
                        for(int i = 0 ; i < arr_byte.size() ; i++) {
                            buffer[i] = arr_byte.get(i).byteValue();
                        }
                        // Send the obtained bytes to the UI A
                        arr_byte = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    } else {
                        arr_byte.add(data);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetootConectionManager.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Write to the connected OutStream.
        // @param buffer  The bytes to write
        public void write(byte[] buffer) {
            try {/*
                byte[] buffer2 = new byte[buffer.length + 2];
                for(int i = 0 ; i < buffer.length ; i++)
                    buffer2[i] = buffer[i];
                buffer2[buffer2.length - 2] = 0x0A;
                buffer2[buffer2.length - 1] = 0x0D;*/
                mmOutStream.write(buffer);
                // Share the sent message back to the UI Activity
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        // The local server socket
        private BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private String mSocketType;
        boolean isRunning = true;

        public AcceptThread() {
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;

            // Create a new listening server socket
            try {
                tmp = mAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, UUID_OTHER_DEVICE);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            setName("AcceptThread" + mSocketType);
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Listen to the server socket if we're not connected
            while (mState != BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED && isRunning) {
                try {
                    // This is a blocking call and will only return on a
                    // successful connection or an exception
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }

                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    synchronized (BluetootConectionManager.this) {
                        switch (mState) {
                            case BluetoothState.STATE_LISTEN:
                            case BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTING:
                                // Situation normal. Start the connected thread.
                                connected(socket, socket.getRemoteDevice());
                                break;
                            case BluetoothState.STATE_NONE:
                            case BluetoothState.STATE_CONNECTED:
                                // Either not ready or already connected. Terminate new socket.
                                try {
                                    socket.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) { }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
                mmServerSocket = null;
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        public void kill() {
            isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to connect with

```
btManager.connect(address);
```

But I get the following error when trying to connect:

```
java.io.IOException: Service discovery failed
```

Comment: did you put Bluetooth permission is Android Manifiest? Like thise :<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

Comment: yes, here are my permissions:  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />